# Time Input Field spacing issue

Tags: xml, input, orbeon, xforms

I am using IE8 and running the form in Orbeon 3.9 CE version Sandbox. I have observed that the time input field has a small issue while showing the content in the field on IE8. After entering the date, the form formats the date and adds either `a.m` or `p.m` to end, but this whole information just overrides on the time image which is on the right most of the field. See the below screen shot.

[image]

However, this issue will not happen on lower versions of IE. I launched the form on Compatibility view and  could not see the issue.

[image]

Also, this issue is happening only when i have my custom fonts and size. Since the entire app is using a standard fonts and size i have to use it in Orbeon forms too.

Below is the sample code

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:f="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/formatting"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    >

    <xhtml:head>

        <style type="text/css">
            input {
                font-size: .95em;
                vertical-align:top;
                font-family: monospace !important;
            }
        </style>
        <xforms:model xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="main-model" >

          <xforms:instance id="form-instance">
            <form>
              <field-1></field-1>
            </form>
          </xforms:instance>

          <xforms:bind id="field-1" nodeset="instance('form-instance')/field-1" type="xforms:time"/>

        </xforms:model>
    </xhtml:head>

    <xhtml:body>

      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Enter Time: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <xforms:input bind="field-1" id="field-1-id" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </xhtml:body>
</xhtml:html>
```

In  this code, if we remove the style it works fine, but i should use it. Hence for a workaround i have identified to use the below css

```
.xforms-type-time { width:115px !important; }
```

So, to sum up is there something a kind of improvement that is possible to make in Orbeon forms engine?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the width of the control is set to `8em`. In my testing here, it does show wider with IE7 than IE8 and Chrome, but there is still enough space for the time with those browsers. If with your CSS the input gets too narrow, then you can override the default CSS to make it wider, as you suggested.